# Specify which plugins to use on a route in Kong dbless mode

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

In dbless mode on kong we can specify which routes to be added on plugin using this declration:

```
plugins:
- name: jwt
  route: <route>
  config: 
    secret_is_base64: false
```

But I need to specify which plugins this route is going to use with something like:

```
route:
- name: getUser
  paths:
    - /user
  plugins: [<plugin1>, <plugin2>]
```

Any way to do this?
I dont want to update all the plugin declarations everytime I add a new API on a service.

Comment: Why not just add the plugins globally or on the service instead of route ?

Comment: @Ôrel Because each route can have different plugins, like multiple configs of rate limit or required auth vs optional auth inside the same service.
My services are not grouped by middleware/plugins it can apply.

Comment: So if you want to have different plugin configuration you have to set specific configuration, so I don"t get your question

Comment: Problem is with how a plugin is attached to a route. Plugin is the top resource, under which we have to declare all the routes. So lets say a new route uses 3 plugins. I ll have to add the route and also update 3 plugins to have this route added. If a route declaration had plugins array then all I ll have to do is add a new route and add 3 plugins in the route declaration itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare your plugins like this:

```yaml
services:
- connect_timeout: 60000
  host: alb.host.dev
  name: service1
  routes:
  - hosts:
    - api.host.com
    - www.host.com
    name: my_host
    methods:
    - GET
    paths:
    - /user
    plugins: 
    - name: plugin1
      config:
        redis_database: 0
        redis_host: redis.dev
        redis_password: null
        redis_port: 6379
        redis_timeout: 2000
    - name: plugin2
      config:
        foo: 1
        bar: 2
```